# How to create TLS Certificate and deploy in APNS server

Tags: xcode, ssl

As per apple latest news "Providers using only SSL 3.0 will need to support TLS as soon as possible to ensure the Apple Push Notification service continues to perform as expected."

I have created a TLS certificate and deployed in the server but getting issue when trying to send push from the server.

I have followed the below link to create the TLS certificate.
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2326/_index.html

If anyone created TLS file and deployed in the server please reply my post.

Thanks in advance